# Firebase Dynamic Link Not Opening App on Android 13 with latest flutter sdk

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen is working in sdk 3.3.9 stable but not in sdk 3.10.5 stable
I have checked & updated packages to latest like core, dynamic_links. Any idea what might be causing this.

problem in summary: if app is in background, on clicking dynamic link the app should be opened but after redirection from browser it does not open the app. (tested in physical device poco f3 android)

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((linkData) async {
      final queryParams = linkData.link.queryParameters;
      DISABLE_ACCOUNT_SYNC_DURING_JOINING = true;    
      bool loginStatus =
          await CommonHelpers.currentUserLoggedInLocallyAndFirebase();
      if (loginStatus) {
        CommonHelpers.checkLinkContentAndRedirect(queryParams);
      } else {
        _navigateToNewScreen(
          queryParams: queryParams,
          appOpeningType: AppOpeningType.DYNAMIC_LINK,
          loggedInStatus: loginStatus,
        );
      }
    }).onError((error) {
      throw Exception(error);
    });
```

Comment: This may help you https://youtu.be/gMqR5quOBg8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651609/dynamic-links-wont-open-in-android-13
refer to this answer with these changes.
(eg: https://example.com/invite/link) is dynamic link. (not uri prefix)
                <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:scheme="https"
                android:pathPrefix="/invite/link" />

this worked for me.